# Inserting part of json object into database only inserts a bracket

Tags: php, json, database

I am trying to insert part of a json object into my database using the following code:

```
$filename = json_encode($_FILES['files']);

// Insert file into database
$insertfile = "
INSERT INTO files1 (filename, name, path, cat_id)
VALUES ('".$filename['name']."', '".$name."', '".$custom_dir."', '".$catid."')";
$insertfilecon = $conn->query($insertfile);
```

ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES AT THE MOMENT, I know above code is not safe.

For some strange reason the first time I tried this, the filename was added to my database.

It added: `199370898.pdf`

Now every upload it just adds `{`

And I don't know why, if I add the json to my database this is shown:

```
{"name":["198970050.pdf"],"type":["application/pdf"],"tmp_name":["/tmp/phpffJUEt"],"error":[0],"size":[24295]}
```

How come I only see a bracket being added?

Comment: `$filename` is a string after `json_encode`, not an array. I'm surprised it works at all. I guess `name` defaults to `0` so you end up echoing the first character of the string. You should be getting a notice.

Comment: @user3783243 Decoding it has the same effect.

Comment: Assuming youare using the `mysqli_` API! Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @twan It is not `json` so you can't decode it. Look at https://3v4l.org/1UTp2 that is your current behavior. I think you want `$_FILES['files']['name']`

Comment: @user3783243 I tried that before, but that just adds `Array` to my database. I've also tried `$_FILES['files'][0]['name']` But that just adds nothing.

Comment: Did you try `$_FILES['files']['name']` ___and forget about the json completely___ which by the way could cause issues as that is the name of the file on the users system, and therefore 2 users can upload a file with the same name

Comment: Can you add the results of `print_r($_FILES)`? Sounds like you are sending multiple files.

Comment: @user3783243 I am not sure how, the file is posted through ajax using the blueimp upload plugin. All code is handled in a remote file, this is why I used json_encode to add in my database in the first place so I could see what is inside `$_FILES['files']`

Comment: So I'm confused what the question is then. Are you trying to store the json, or just store the filename? And if just the filename... why does `$_FILES['files']['name'][0]` not work?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am just trying to store the filename, and I have no clue why it does not work. I've tried about 10 different methods.

Comment: Well, according to your json example provided (and the array rules of the $_FILES superglobal when multiple files *may* exist)... the `$_FILES['files']['name'][0]` should work! lol... so I'm baffled why this is not the case :(